# Is there a way to create JToolBar (floating) on start?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtoolbar

I want to create a JToolBar without adding it into any JFrame window. If I have to add it, then how can I make it such that the toolbar is created as a floating toolbar not a docking toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are going to need to override `BasicToolBarUI` and set the toolbars parent to an instance of JDialog which is bound to the current frame, that way you can float a toolbar by default and keep it on top of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to some panel and then make it float immediately by calling setFloating on its BasicToolBarUI, no need to override classes:

```
JPanel someParentPanel = ...; // BorderLayout?
JToolBar toolBar = ...; // Your toolBar

// It is mandatory for the JToolBar to have a parent component before calling ui.setFloating
someParentPanel.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST);

// Now, make it float
BasicToolBarUI ui = (BasicToolBarUI) toolBar.getUI();
ui.setFloating(true, new Point(0, 0)); // Pass any point where you want it to appear
```

You can also make it dock by using the same method, but passing `false` as first parameter.